# Python data frame Search against another data frame

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I am trying to figure out the best way to compare a data frame with a list of values ( almost 180 values) for example as given below

`['bizservice.consulting','bizservice.datamgmt','bizservice.hr']`
against another data frame with 4 M records with a field value given below.

```
['consumerservices?5', 'hospitality?5', 'hospitality.travel?5']
['bizservice?12', 'bizservice.hr?12']
['hospitality?83', 'hospitality.lodging?83']
['bizservice.techconsulting?16', 'bizservice?16', 'software?16']
```

Not sure how to make the comparison and retrieve the matching records from the second data frame based on the first data frame which doesn't have the numerical code.

This is what I tried

```
import pandas as pd
industry = pd.read_csv('industry.csv')
data= pd.read_csv('rawdata.csv') 
datafilter=data[data["industry"].isin (industry)]
```

But this will help only if the list in data is exactly matching with the industry data frame   and I tried 'contains' but it can be used only with strings